# Javascript - Automatically switch/create to another row if a row is filled with 4 cells in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, xmlhttprequest

I think that the title is self-explanatory. I am retrieving data using `XMLHttpRequest` and the data is getting appended into columns of a table. I decided to only allow a row to have only 4 columns inside it and if another item exists then it should be appended into another row. This is what I have done:

```
//...
//unneccessary
//...
            var album_photos = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < album_photos.length; i++) {
                if(!isInArray(album_photos[i].Image_ID, image_ids)) {
                    var tr = document.getElementById("tiare");
                    if(i % 4 == 0) {
                        tr = document.createElement("tr");
                        document.getElementById("images").appendChild(tr);

                    }
//...
//creating elements to be append
//...
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.appendChild(imagewrap);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagemenu);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg1);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg2);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagewrapimg);
                    image_ids.push(album_photos[i].Image_ID);
//...![enter image description here][1]
//unneccessary
//...
```

And this is the markup:

```
<table width="80%" id="images">
    <tr id="tiare">

    </tr>
</table>
```

See how it's not getting splitted correctly:
[image]

How can I achieve this, my logic is not working at all! What should I do?

P.S: No jQuery solution allowed. :)

**Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)**

**UPDATE:** I changed my code into this:

```
function getAlbumImages() {
    var xhr2 = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr2.open('GET', 'admin/images_data.php');

    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200) {
            var oldtable = document.getElementById("images");
            var newtable = oldtable.cloneNode();
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");

            var album_photos = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < album_photos.length; i++) {
                if(!isInArray(album_photos[i].Image_ID, image_ids)) {
                    if(i%4 == 0 && i != 0){
                        newtable.appendChild(tr);
                        tr = document.createElement('tr');        
                    }
                    var td = document.createElement('td');
                    var imagewrap = document.createElement('div');
                    imagewrap.className = "image-wrap";
                        var imagemenu = document.createElement('div');
                        imagemenu.className = "image-menu";
                            var imagemenuimg1 = document.createElement('img');
                            imagemenuimg1.src = "img/edit_img.png";
                            var imagemenuimg2 = document.createElement('img');
                            imagemenuimg2.src = "img/close.png";
                        var imagewrapimg = document.createElement('img');
                        imagewrapimg.className = "thumbnail";
                        imagewrapimg.src = "admin/album_photos/" + album_photos[i].Image_Path;
                        imagewrapimg.onclick = function() { showBigImage(this); };
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    td.appendChild(imagewrap);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagemenu);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg1);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg2);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagewrapimg);
                    image_ids.push(album_photos[i].Image_ID);
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            newtable.appendChild(tr);
            oldtable.parentNode.replaceChild(newtable, oldtable);
        }
    }
    xhr2.send(null);
}
```

This function is called inside an `setInterval` with 5000 milliseconds break.

The problem coming now is that it disappears after 5 seconds. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Can you describe where your current code goes wrong and can you show what the HTML generally looks like in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that `i` and `i % 4` is not the images in your table, it's the images in the returned data. The two will differ as soon as you encounter an image already in your array. You need to use an index for the `i % 4` that is the actual number of images in the table.  You could use a separate count of how many images are in the table that you intialize with:

```
var imageCnt = document.getElementById("images").getElementsByTagName("td").length
```

And, the increment that any time you add an image to the table and then check `%imageCnt % 4` to decide when to add a new row.

Then, don't you want to be adding images to the LAST row in the table, not the first row in the table because that's where the extra slots will be and where the new empty row goes.  You will be adding images to the last row when you've just created a new row, but not when your last row is partially filled when you start.  In that case, you'll be adding images to the first row.  You can start with the last row

```
var table = document.getElementById("images");
var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
```

---

Applying these to your first example of code would work like this:

```
//...
//unneccessary
//...
            var album_photos = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            var table = document.getElementById("images");
            var tableBody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
            // initialize cell count
            var cellCount = table.getElementsByTagName("td").length;
            for(var i = 0; i < album_photos.length; i++) {
                if(!isInArray(album_photos[i].Image_ID, image_ids)) {
                    if (cellCount % 4 == 0 && cellCount !== 0) {
                        // make new row and append it to the table body
                        lastRow = document.createElement("tr");
                        tableBody.appendChild(lastRow);
                    }
//...
//creating elements to be append
//...
                    td.appendChild(imagewrap);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagemenu);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg1);
                    imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg2);
                    imagewrap.appendChild(imagewrapimg);
                    // best to append the new cell when it's fully formed
                    lastRow.appendChild(td);
                    ++cellCount;
                    image_ids.push(album_photos[i].Image_ID);
//...![enter image description here][1]
//unneccessary
```

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - I have no idea what you're trying to do now.  You're cloning the original table whenever you start?  Why?  I don't see that you've addressed either of the issues in my answer.  You're not keeping a count of the actual images in the table and you're not starting to insert images on the last row of the existing table.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - added an example of modifying your code.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined" this is what I get. :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - on what line of code?  Do you understand the two issues I've described in my answer?

Comment: lastRow.appendChild(td); but now when I reversde my markup aswell. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: All the images are shwon in one line. :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - there was a typo in my code.  This line `tableBody.appendChild(tr);` should be `tableBody.appendChild(lastRow);`

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - when you says things like "still it doesn't solve it" and don't offer any new information on what's happening now, I can't help you at all.  Either describe what error occurs on what line or describe what the output it doing.  All I can see is your words.  You haven't offered a running body of code for me to see or fix.  I only have your words.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - I just noticed that we also have to increment the `cellCount` which I added to my code.

Comment: Ok, sorry. The result is coming the same. All images in one row.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - glad you got it figured out.  Sorry for my typos.  It's hard to write perfect code you can't run or test.